# How to open a link new tab with print command?

Tags: html, printing, hyperlink

I have a hyperlink with contains third party website link. I want to open this link in new tab **with print command**. How can i do this?
**Suppose:**

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Print</a>
```

Note: I know how to open a link in new TAB/Window. I want to know how to open with PRINT DIALOG.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<a href="javascript: w=window.open('http://yoursite.com/LinkToThePDF.pdf'); w.print(); w.close(); ">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​print pdf</a>
```

Comment: I have a web PDF link. i want to open this link in new tab. I can open it in new tab. New tab now display PDF file in browser. Now i want to open this link in new tab with Print Dialog Open.

Comment: Try if this works then: `<a href="javascript: w=window.open('http://yoursite.com/LinkToThePDF.pdf'); w.print(); w.close(); ">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​print pdf</a>`

Comment: I found that it worked better without the `w.close();`

Comment: but when i put a php or html page, browser just print a blank page. `<a href="javascript: w=window.open('http://google.com'); w.print(); w.close(); ">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​print pdf</a>`

Answer (score 6):

This method works well for me.

```
<a href="/url/" onclick="window.open(this.href).print(); return false">
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no way for a website to cause a browser to load a third party website *and* display the print dialog for it automatically.

Answer (score 3):

```
<img src="print.png" style="cursor:hand" onclick="window.frames['pact'].print();"><iframe name="pact" src="pact.pdf" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: This works nicely, that it stays on the same page, opening an unseen iframe does not seem so desirable always.

Answer (score 0):

This absolutely worked for me. I'm coding a site in Angular 6.

```
<a href="doc.pdf" onClick="window.print(); return false">Print</a>
```

Here's my source ([enter link description here](https://it.toolbox.com/question/adding-a-print-hyperlink-on-a-page-to-print-pdf-file-012208)) but watch out for double quotes in the originak source.

:)

Comment: Actually this prints the page instead of the PDF file

Answer (score -4):

This is depend on your browsers, you can enable the tab for new link, If you are using Firefox you can enable the tab using **Firefox -> Options -> options -> open a new windows in a new tab instead** option

Comment: Thanks for quick response.I just want to know open in new tab with PRINT DIALOG.

Comment: do you want to keep the PRINT text on the new tab or previous tab?

Comment: do not want to keep this text in new tab only print dialog.

Comment: You can't set the print dialog, because the print command is being sent directly from the PDF application and not the browser(which the JS interacts with)

Comment: If you are using php, javascript you can.PDFs have Javascript support. you need to have auto print capabilities when a PHP-generated PDF was created and you need to use FPDF to get it to work: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script36.php

Comment: check this one also http://www.ehow.com/how_7352227_use-javascript-print-pdf.html