# How to open a url in new window and then trigger ctrl + p (print)?

Tags: angular, iframe, window-object

I have iframe within a div and have a print button, on clicking print I want to open a new tab and trigger print action for the url being shown in iframe.
I am using Angular 7.

Solutions I tried so far:

[How to open a link new tab with print command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276416/how-to-open-a-link-new-tab-with-print-command)

**html**

```
<div>
      <iframe #iframe [src]="url"  width="100%" id='event-print-iframe'
          name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" >
            </iframe>

<button (click)='print()'>Print</button>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
 import {
  //...
  ElementRef,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
 @ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;
     print()
      {
        let content = this.url;
        let doc =  this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument || this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow;
        doc.open();
        doc.write(content);
        doc.close();

      }
```

Solution From [iframe inside angular2 component, Property 'contentWindow' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38457662/iframe-inside-angular2-component-property-contentwindow-does-not-exist-on-typ)

**Error using above solution:**

> ERROR DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://localhost:4200" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

I have a url and I just want to open it in new tab and print without clicking Ctrl+p

Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 1):

[image: See I am able to open the link in a new tab and the print window appears.]----------

---

You can install this npm module and provide any of the key combinations that you wish to execute.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-hotkeys

You will have to provide a target blank href for opening the url in a new tab.

You can try this

```
  ngAfterViewInIt() {
           this.printView();
  }


   printView() { 
           window.print();
   }
```

Hope this helps :).

Comment: Thanks @Abhijeet Chakravorty for answering.
Ctrl+p can be done with window.print(). My issue is that window.print() executes before window.open() therefore print does not work as intended.

Comment: @Harsimer Have you tried implementing it using the life cycle hook ngAfterViewInit() ?

Comment: How can I call a function in lifecycle hook? I am executing window.open and window.print within a function.

Comment: You can call it just like a normal function => this.printView(). window.print() has to be called separately. Are both the components different where you navigate from and navigate to?

Comment: I have content in iframe and on clicking a button I have to open a new browser tab and print the new tab content which should be same as content of iframe. I am not navigating anywhere.

Comment: @Harsimer Oh Okay so you are printing the same page but only when a user clicks on the print button.

Comment: @Harsimer  You need to create a broadcast event and subscribe to that particular function when a user clicks on the button.

Comment: thanks for helping. I just want to do what is being solved in accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276416/how-to-open-a-link-new-tab-with-print-command
But this solution is not working for me. so I posted this question. but no luck.

Comment: Hey it’s cool and It’s all about learning. I shall paste the JS fiddle link in a while. This problem is not difficult I shall write it out now :D.

Comment: Abhijeet Thanks a lot mate for your time!

Comment: @Harsimer Please check this code once it works for me. The only thing that I am not doing is that I am not calling the close function and you are most welcome :).                                                                                                  <div>
  <iframe #iframe [src]="url" width="100%" id="event-print-iframe" name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <a href="javascript: w=window.open('http://localhost:4200/home'); w.print();" target="_blank">
    <button type="button">Print</button>  
  </a>
</div>

Comment: @Harsimer Please refer to the image also which I have attached with the solution.

Comment: I solved problem to some extent. I used this function.   print() {
    let mywindow = window.open();
    mywindow.document.write(this.content);
    setTimeout(() => {
      const value = mywindow.print();
      mywindow.close();
    }, 6000);
  } 
Where this.content is content I received after hitting this.url. So once url return html document I enable print button and when print button is clicked above function is called. Thanks for your precious time and help.